# How to create a file root user can't delete

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, root, user-permissions

On Linux systems, I have a file I want to preserve from (even accidental) deletion.
How can I create a file even the root user can't delete?

For instance, by trying:

```
# touch file
# chmod 000 file
# chown <somebody>:<somebody> file
# rm file
```

root user is able to delete the file (through the last command).

How can I avoid root user to (even temporary) delete the file?

Comment: Essentially, you can't make root not be root.  Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I'm curious: let's suppose I want to prevent even root to write/delete a file, even temporary.

Comment: [You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://serverfault.com/help/dont-ask); I fear this is one is therefore off-topic.

Comment: Changed the description, accordingly to a problem I now have...

Comment: Formatting the entire disk is not "deleting the file"  but you still lose the file. What you want (safeguard the file) is not what you would achieve by making the file non-deleteable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set its immutable bit to prevent even root from deleting it:

```
chattr +i file
```

Comment: root can still delete it, though you have turned it into a two-step process: remove immutable bit, delete file.

Comment: @MadHatter is right, root can do anything, just an extra hop here and there

Comment: Of course root can do that. My purpose is to avoid accidental removal.